# python web server benchmarks lower than expected

Tags: python, web, nginx, cherrypy

I have a cherrrypy application server that is sitting behind nginx (reverse proxy). Cherrypy is being run as daemon process per core (my server as 4 cores) and nginx (also configured with 4 workers) performs the load balancing on the incoming requests.

I'm benchmarking GETing the front page of my webapp using [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey). For values of 200 concurrent requests and a total of 10k requests, I reach about 400-500 rps. I need to be able to handle at least 10x that. When I look at the histogram:

```
 Response time histogram:
  0.014 [1] |
  0.721 [9193]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  1.429 [693]   |■■■
  2.137 [13]    |
  2.844 [0]     |
  3.552 [88]    |
  4.259 [0]     |
  4.967 [0]     |
  5.674 [0]     |
  6.382 [0]     |
  7.089 [12]    |
```

It's very weird that some requests take so long (1.5-7 seconds) to process, considering there isn't any IO operations involved in the main page URL handler, just generating a static template and sending it over.

How can I get an idea about what is my bottleneck, before I go down some rabbit hole of premature optimisation? Is the cherrypy? python itself? my hardware?

Comment: You could try the same deployment on different hardware - like spin up AWS VMs of different size and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition on what you mentioned, consider the automatic [python garbage collector](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/).

If you need 500 X 10 request per seconds, then the CherryPy/Cheroot threadpool (10 threads by default) will have a hard time unless you increment the thread pool size and maybe add more CPUs to run more CherryPy daemons.

If you have 4 daemons and the default thread pool, then effectively CherryPy has 4 X 10 = 40 threads that can do work at the same time (ignoring the OS scheduler and the GIL).

For the kind of load that you're describing an async/event based server seems more appropriate. Or you will have to be more *smart* in your nginx proxy, trying to serve anything static directly from nginx and only some request to reach CherryPy.